# Cannot resolve symbol 'EnableJpaRespositories' even though specified in build.gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, gradle, spring-data-jpa

For some reason, I'm unable to get a module within my project to detect that it has the dependencies in place to pick up `@EnableJpaRepositories`. Despite having `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'` specified in my build.gradle file, when I run gradle to try and compile, I get the following error:

```sh
./gradlew clean build 

> Task :rest:compileJava FAILED
/Users/pasdeignan/git/pasciifinance/rest/src/main/java/com/pasciitools/pasciifinance/rest/PasciifinanceApplication.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
@EnableJpaRespositories(basePackages="com.pasciitools.pasciifinance")
 ^
  symbol: class EnableJpaRespositories
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

### Background

I have a multi-module Spring project that I'm building where I'm trying to store the JPA pieces in a `common` module and the REST services in a `rest` module. The `rest` module is also where my `SpringBootApplication` lives. When I start up the application, I get the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field accountRepo in com.pasciitools.pasciifinance.rest.PasciifinanceApplication required a bean of type 'com.pasciitools.pasciifinance.common.repositories.AccountRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.pasciitools.pasciifinance.common.repositories.AccountRepository' in your configuration.
```

#### Project Structure

```
pasciifinance
└── build.gradle (empty)
└── settings.gradle
└── common
     └── build.gradle
     └── src
          └── main/java/com/pasciitools/pasciifinance/common
                └── entity
                └── repository
                    └── AccountRepository.java
└── rest
     └── build.gradle
     └── src
         └── main/java/com/pasciitools/pasciifinance/rest
             └── PasciiFinanceApplication.java
             └── restservice
                 └── RestService.java
```

#### PasciiFinanceApplication.java

```java
package com.pasciitools.pasciifinance.rest;

import com.pasciitools.pasciifinance.common.entity.Account;
import com.pasciitools.pasciifinance.common.entity.AccountEntry;
import com.pasciitools.pasciifinance.common.repository.AccountEntryRepository;
import com.pasciitools.pasciifinance.common.repository.AccountRepository;
import com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.annotation.EnableEncryptableProperties;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@EnableEncryptableProperties
@EnableJpaRespositories(basePackages="com.pasciitools.pasciifinance")
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.pasciitools.pasciifinance")
public class PasciifinanceApplication {


    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepo;

    @Autowired
    private AccountEntryRepository entryRepo;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PasciifinanceApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PasciifinanceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

#### build.gradle (rest module)

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.pascii-tools'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59'
    implementation 'com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot:3.0.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

#### build.gradle (common)

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.pascii-tools'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in `@EnableJpaRespositories`.

You'll need to rename it to `@EnableJpaRepositories`, as you've asked in your question.